# Why node in Raft start with follower state? Can they start with candidate state?

Tags: raft

I think there is no different. May be start with candidate state may take longer to  elect a leader than start with follower state.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple logic to hold: if a follower does not hear from the leader for some time, then it becomes a candidate. This works for both new clusters and in case a node rejoining after being disconnected. Simple.

Otherwise: If a coming back node becomes a candidate immediately, that will be its term? Complicated.

There is an interesting case with becoming a candidate. Let's say we have a working cluster with 5 nodes. One node becomes disconnected. Based on basic raft rules, the node will become candidate, as it won't hear the heartbeat from the leader. The basic implementation will keep proposing itself as a leader by increasing its term and reaching out to other nodes. But the reach will never happen, as the node is disconnected.

Naive implementation will keep increasing term until the node is connected back to the network. When that will happen, two things will happen:

- this candidate has term much larger than the current term in the cluster; but this candidate won't be able to win the election as its log is behind
- current leader will eventually learn that there is a node with larger term. Raft is simple: if there is a larger term, leader gives up its role and a new election happens.